# Is there an appropriate time to routinely delete yarn.lock / package-lock.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Is it appropriate to periodically delete the yarn.lock file to allow yarn to install the latest versions of dependencies and subdependencies from within the semver ranges specified in package.json? The same question goes for package-lock.json and npm.

The reason I ask is that I have worked on a project in the past where some dependencies were set to very old versions. The team (rightly or wrongly) perceived it as a risky change to update a dependency that was two major versions behind the current version. So I want to keep dependencies fairly up to date and avoid big-bang dependency updates.

My team uses the git-flow branching model (https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). So I am wondering whether it would be appropriate for us to start a new yarn.lock in our develop branch after each release is merged to the master branch.

---

EDIT:

As pointed out by @str, my original phrasing (unchanged above) was a bit inconsistent.

The part where I was inconsistent was that I was asking about getting the most up to date version within a semver range but then I gave an example where I worked on a project that was "two major versions behind".

It is indeed true that the semver range operators that are most commonly used (in my experience) will not allow yarn or npm to install a version that has the major value higher than the version in the range expression. For example if you use the npm semver calculator at https://semver.npmjs.com/ and enter package lodash and range ^2.0.0 it will only match the 2.x.x versions.

However, it is possible to specify a semver range that includes major version updates. If you go to https://semver.npmjs.com/ and enter package lodash and range >2 you will see that this range matches all the 3.x.x versions and all the 4.x.x versions.

Anyway, the question that I was intending to ask was more about allowing dependencies to update in general than the specific case of allowing them to update to a newer major version. The example about being two major versions behind was my attempt to refer to a situation where updating the dependencies starts to seem risky so the team starts putting it off further.

It seems to me like a yarn.lock or package-lock.json is useful in the short term because it makes the project build more consistently across different machines, and also useful in the long term because it allows the team to check out a historic revision and build it the same as it was built when it was created. But I also think it could be a good practice for a project to periodically have the lock removed so that all of the dependencies can update to the latest versions within their semver ranges. Has anyone got experience with such a procedure that they could comment on here? Or could anyone tell me a compelling reason why it would be a bad idea?

Comment: its a per-dependency thing as a general rule you want to keep up to date but alot of the time updating them breaks a lot at takes some time to resolve the issues if you even can.

Comment: Deleting the lock file will not change anything, the package.json needs to be updated to upgrade to newer (major) versions.

Comment: The package-lock file is supposed to enable you to go "back in time" in terms of what dependencies you have. Although I find it a bit useless, considering your code is already in version control, so if you aren't sloppy, you'd be able to do the same via the VCS. My personal preference would be to just avoid the lock files - they just introduce noise in commits.

Comment: @vlaz "[package-lock.json ... This file is intended to be committed into source repositories](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)".

Comment: @str I know it says that. I just find it redundant - it's doing the VCS's job...by being committed to the VCS. It only changes content when you change package.json and you generally only do that when you need to do larger code changes that rely on new/updated dependencies. If you do that, you can't really decouple it from the code changes needed, so going back via the lock file means your project ceases to work. A VCS rollback should leave it in a working state. If you just update a dependency for bugfixes or something, you can still rely on VCS to roll back. Tho, I said: personal preference.

Comment: @vlaz "If you just update a dependency for bugfixes or something, you can still rely on VCS to roll back" That is not always true and precisely the reason why the lock file was introduced in the first place. While your own dependencies might not change if you lock them to a fixed version, your dependencies' semver-defined dependencies might. The lock file ensures that "subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates".

Comment: @str again, that's my personal preference. The whole system is badly designed, IMO, since multiple runs of `npm install` should be producing identical stuff anyway.

Comment: @vlaz Well, the lock file exists to ensure exactly that.